# Socket P2P and Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I'm attempting to create a messaging application (more than likely been done in other ways) and I'm using threading so I can send or receive a message at any time

I have used classes for each thread, one for receiving a message one for sending

## Sending files

```
class snd (threading.Thread):
    def run (self):
        while True:
            msg = input("You: ")
            if msg == endprompt:
                closecon()
                break
            else:
                s.send(bytes(msg, "UTF-8"))
                sen()
                pass
```

and it is called after by this:

```
def sen ():
    s.start()
s = snd()
```

Receiving is similar, just vague changes as you'd expect

## Receiving

```
class rcv (threading.Thread):
    def run (self):
        while True:
            reply = s.recv(2048)
            print("User: ", reply.decode("UTF-8"))
            rec()
```

again this is called like this:

```
def rec ():
    r.start()
r = rcv()
```

## The Problem

"send" is not an attribute of snd
same with recv I'm assuming

This is a problem with triggering the send on my socket from in an object
so I tried a few things

#### My attempt to solve this

One being:
changing `from socket import *`
to `import socket as sck`

I then went on to trying to add things like this to the classes, e.g `class snd (threading.Thread, sck.send)`

This again didn't work and spat out the error:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'send'

## Question

How can I solve this? so i can send messages inside the objects?

#### Aditional info:

```
s = sck.socket(sck.AF_INET, sck.SOCK_STREAM)
```

~~~~

```
def closecon ():
    s.close()
```

~~~~

```
def con ():
    s.connect((host, port))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first let me point out the simple problem that might make your situation clear.  Lets analyze what's going on between these code snippets:

```
s = sck.socket(sck.AF_INET, sck.SOCK_STREAM) # s defined at the global level

def closecon ():
    # python looks for s in the local namespace, doesn't find it
    # and uses the global s above.
    s.close()  # s.close() refers to the socket object's (defined above) .close() method
def con ():
    s.connect((host, port))  # Again s not defined locally, so it uses the global s.
```

Using globals within your functions, or anything really is often considered bad practice, and ultimately makes your code hard to read, even for yourself.  The specific problem you are having comes down to this snippet:

```
def sen ():
    s.start()
s = snd()  # s is now a snd object, no longer a socket
```

By redefining what `s` refers to, your class `snd`, whenever you run() it is using that definition of `s` instead of the original socket.

```
class snd (threading.Thread):
    def run (self):
        while True:
            msg = input("You: ")
            if msg == endprompt:
                closecon()
                break
            else:
                s.send(bytes(msg, "UTF-8")) # snd objects (subclassed Thread) has no send() method
                sen()
                pass
```

If you are able to follow me until now, you realise that whenever the code in `run()` of your `snd` class runs, it gets to the line `s.send(bytes(msg, "UTF-8"))` and is using the current global definition of `s` because there is no `s` definition in the scope it is locally in.  To fix this, you can make the variable names for your socket object and your snd object different from eachother, and update your code where you are wanting to refer to the socket, and the snd object with their new names.   I DO NOT recommend this as a solution to your code however, even if it might work.

**What I Recommend**

In your `Thread` subclasses, you should overwrite the `__init__()` method of `threading.Thread` to include accepting a socket object.  Your code for your snd class (and similiarly your rec class) would then look more like:

```
class snd (threading.Thread):
    ## Added __init__ override
    def __init__(self, sock):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock = sock
    def run (self):
        while True:
            msg = input("You: ")
            if msg == endprompt:
                closecon()
                break
            else:
                self.sock.send(bytes(msg, "UTF-8")) # Now we use the socket specifically given to this object
                sen()
                pass # You don't need this
```

When you want to use your thread, you simply need to modify your code a bit:

```
my_sock = sck.socket(sck.AF_INET, sck.SOCK_STREAM)
sender = snd(my_sock)
sender.start()
```

Note your code will still not work at this point, because your con() and closecon() functions need to be rewritten as such:

```
def closecon(sock):
    sock.close()

def con(sock, host, port):
    sock.connect((host,port))
```

Ultimately there are several other problems in your code that have to be reworked, but I think I have left enough information for you to figure out how to do that, or to learn out how to figure it out.  If you dont want to read any of the more basic explanations below about python, I will at least leave you with a few points:

- Networking is really complicated.
- Sockets are really low level and make networking hard.
- Threading is an advanced tool that requires sound program flow understanding to pull off properly.
- Subclassing and inheritance is a moderately advanced concept.

If you lack a solid foundational understanding of the language fundamentals, attempting to code using any of the above points will be a battle of copy-paste and confusion that arises from small holes in understanding.  I ultimately recommend you get a python book or perhaps *closely* read online tutorials before attempting something like networking with sockets and threading.  If you are just attempting to get something to work, and are more focused on other code, I would recommend looking into other more high-level networking libraries for python.  Other than that, good luck in your project.

If you want to make your code make more sense to you and others, learning about the difference between local and global variables, and the concept of variable scopes in python will help you understand why several pieces of your code are going to fail.  It will help you organize your code much nicer as it gets larger.  If you just want a quick run down however, continue reading. I am no expert in python or programming, so perhaps there may be a mistake here or there, but I will try my best to explain.

**Scopes**

When your python code is running and comes across a variable name, it checks to see what that variable is defined as.  First it checks the local namespace, and then goes up from there, all the way to the highest namespace, the global namespace.  Note that it never looks into lower namespaces for definitions.  This means that you can reuse variable names at different scope levels without them ever conflicting.  If you don't know what a namespace is, just think of it as where you are at in the code.  For example,

```
x=1 # Here you are at the global scope/namespace
def func():
    x=2 # << Here you are in func's namespace
print(x) # Back out at the global namespace
```

If you think this code results in a `2` printing to the screen, then you were wrong.  The `x=2` line is within the scope of func, and the `print(x)` line is at the global level.  When `print(x)` is executed, it looks for the value of `x` starting at the global scope, and this is defined in the first line as `x=1`.  When you define variables as a local variable in a given scope, they are generally destroyed when you leave that scope.  So if you call `func()`, it sets `x=2` in the local scope, and then exits the function.  By doing `return` or just finishing a function, we are leaving its scope and the variable x as defined in the scope is destroyed (dereferenced and garbage collected).  Since the contents of func are at a lower scope than the global scope, code executed at the global level never sees values assigned in it.

So scopes make functions and classes pretty isolated, but the solution to that is to pass arguments to these constructs.  By passing an argument to a function, they set variables defined in their local scope to values passed to them from another scope. To explain, to do what this code does with args:

```
def func(value):
    print(value)
# By passing 100 to func(), there is essentially 
# an invisible line in func that does 'value=100'.
func(100)
```

You must do this with globals:

```
def func():
    value = x
    print(value)
# By not using arguments, we have to manually do that invisible
# assignment of value=100 by setting x=100 and then the function setting value=x
x=100
func()
```

To understand the utility this provides, over just letting python search the global scope for variables, these two snippets will both print `2` to the screen

Using function arguments:

```
x = 1
def func_args(value):
    print(value*2)

func_args(x)
```

Using globals:

```
x=1
def func_globals():
    print(x*2)

func_globals()
```

However, note that `func_globals()` will only print `x*2`, whereas `func_args(value)` will print `value*2` for ANY value passed to it.  This means that in order to use `func_globals()` like `func_args()`, you have to either know that `x` is set to what you want at the moment of calling `func_globals()`, or manually set it to the value you want to work on every time you call it.  With `func_args()`, you only need to know what you are passing in to the function as `value`.

This has by no means been a thorough explanation of variable scopes and namespaces, but hopefully you get some basic understanding of what a scope is.  There is good information on the internet about this sort of thing in python, and I would recommend getting familiar with the concepts, as they are very core to how code is structured in python and other languages.

Comment: This is an AMAZING explanation and i have marked it as correct, you have enlightened me on what i have done wrong, how i can fix it and ways to dive deeper into this. you deserve a great amount of notice for this as it is very in depth and precise. Thank you sir. Seriously

Comment: @Ashmoreinc Glad I could be of help!